# how to convert the datetime value to hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have datetime value as

1. 2010-04-07 09:00:00.000
2. 2010-04-07 14:30:00.000

how to convert the 14:30 to 2:30 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(7), Myvalue, 100), 7)
```

Even better would be to do this in the client code...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do it in a query if so look.

```
select date_format(date, "%Y-%m-%d %r") from table_name
```

also look at  [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

FOR MSSQL YOU SHOULD USE [convert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa237895) method

Comment: Thanks for yr reply..but im using MSSQL. so there is no date_format command as recognizable one

Comment: use convert method for MSSQL likn is given in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**gbn**, didn't you mean `SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(AT-LEAST-19), Myvalue, 100), 7)` ?